# jQuery Slider Description each function

Tags: jquery, each, carousel

I have created a carousel slider with jQuery. But i am having problems getting the description to update after each slide. The slider is built up like:

```
<div id="sliderwrapper">
   <div id="slider_controlpanel">
      <a href="" class="slider_left" data-name="slider_button"></a>
      <a href="" class="slider_right" data-name="slider_button"></a>
      <div id="slider_description"></div>
   </div>  
    <ul>
        <li data-number="1" data-description="blabla">IMG</li>
        <li data-number="2" data-description="obladioblada">IMG</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I did in jQuery is:

```
$('#sliderwrapper ul li:visible').each(function() {
    var currentDesc = $('#slider_description').text();
    var newDesc = $(this).attr('data-description');
    $('#slider_description').removeData(currentDesc);
    $('#slider_description').text(newDesc);
});
```

But somehow it doesn't update but rather stays on the first one. And from what I've gathered, the each function works as a loop, and for each visible slide it should run. Or am I totally wrong an this isn't supposed to work?

If you need the information of how the carousel is built just comment please!

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue? Code looks okay.

Comment: @mattytommo sure, gimme a minute!

Comment: here you go(couldn't edit comment): http://jsfiddle.net/2S3Gz/

Comment: Thanks, can you describe what the fiddle is meant to be doing?

Comment: When you aren't hovering the slider it is on autoslide and if you hover then the two buttons(left/right) pop up along with the description. since i dont have the images for the buttons they are invisible on jsfiddle but in the middle left and right you can press the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... What I get you are trying to do is simply show data from `data-description` attribute of the `li` currently being shown. I have modified and commented changes in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2S3Gz/1/).